# Problemas com a atualização de um projeto angular para a versão 7

Tags: angularjs, webpack, atualização

Estou com um problema na atualização de um projeto angular para o angular 7 e não estou sabendo resolver.
O meu projeto já funciona o `npm i` mas quando eu tento executar o projeto ele aponta o seguinte erro
`ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.` Dependências do projeto (package.json)[image: Dependências do projeto (package.json)]
dependencias dev com a mensagem de erro
[image: dependencias dev com a mensagem de erro]
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][3]

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.